# Add Seperate Sum Functions to an IQueryable LINQ Statement

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, radgrid, telerik-grid

I'm looking to populate a Telerik RadGrid with an IQueryable DataSource but include 5 Total columns inside that Grid. I have built separate functions for the Totals when I create individual reports, but am having some trouble iterating them into my current LINQ statement for the Grid.

My current LINQ statement looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable GetUnapprovedTimesheets(string Period)
    {
        DataContext Data = new DataContext();

        var Times = (from c in Data.System_Times
                     where c.Period == Period && c.Status == 1
                     orderby c.Employee.LName
                     select c).GroupBy(s => s.EmployeeID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

        return Times;
    }
```

This statement grabs the Timesheets for the Period entered, and shows the records with a status of 1, these are then displayed grouped by EmployeeID. This statement pulls everything into the Grid properly but I would like to also add Totals for Regular, Overtime, Travel, and Sub.

The functions I have built separately for dynamic reporting look something like this:

```
public static decimal? GetTotalReg(int EmployeeID, string Period)
    {
        DataContext Data = new DataContext();
        var Total = (from c in Data.Times
                     where c.EmployeeID == EmployeeID && c.Period == Period && c.PayCode == "211"
                     select c.Hours);

        return Total.Sum();
    }
```

Is there any way to incorporate the Second Statement into the First? (Keeping in mind that I will have to incorporate not just one, but 5 Sum statements)

This one statement will then be used as an IQueryable DataSource for my RadGrid, called by DataField=" " of the RadGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static IQueryable GetUnapprovedTimesheets(string period)
{
   DataContext data = new DataContext();

   var times = data
                   .Where(a => a.Period == period && a.Status == 1)
                   .OrderBy(a => a.Employee.LName)
                   .GroupBy(a => a.EmployeeID)
                   .Select(
                      a => new{
                               System_Time = a.FirstOrDefault(),
                               TotalReg = data.Times
                                           .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == a.Key 
                                                    && b.Period == period
                                                    && b.PayCode == "211")
                                           .Sum(b => b.Hours)
                              }
                          );

   return times;
}
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, I just noticed the `GetTotalReg` call uses a different entity. I'll modify my answer.

**Update:** TotalReg is now summed from `data.Times`